# Database error while working with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

What I am trying to achieve is quite simple. I want just to have a local database file from whom I can display the records in a listview, by using Entity Framework. Problem is, each time I build it, I get this error:

> 'DiaryEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'DiaryEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My database is called `Diary`, and I have only one table called `Entries` which contain columns `Title`, `Date` and `Content`. And here are my files:

```html
//main.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace diary
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (diary.DiaryEntities de = new DiaryEntities())
            {
                var diaries = (from m in de.Diary select m.Title);
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(diaries.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
//DiaryEntities.Context.cs
namespace jurnal1
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class DiaryEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DiaryEntities() : base("name=DiaryEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<DiaryEntities>Diary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: shome the model of Entries, and change :  public virtual DbSet<DiaryEntities>Diary { get; set; } to  public DbSet<Entries>Diary { get; set; }

Comment: Your `DbSet<>` should have the entity type as the generic parameter, not the type of the context itself (`DbSet<Diary>`?)

Comment: @haim770 If I put Diary in DbSet then I get "the type or namespace Diary could not be found"

Comment: @hanoc salinas I got same output

Comment: you need an entity(class) with same properties of your table in database, then on dbSet you need change how my last coment

Comment: @henocsalinas could you show how u write it ? and where do I put it ?

Comment: i add an answer, if work for you, please mark the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this:

```
namespace jurnal1 {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

        public partial class DiaryEntities : DbContext {

            public DiaryEntities ( )
                : base ( "name=DiaryEntities" ) {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder ) {

            }
            public DbSet<Entries> Diary { get; set; }

        }

        [Table("entries")]
        public class Entries {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

[check the GITHUB project](https://github.com/enoksaju/EFModel/tree/master/EFModel) i try this, i think the problem is: the model needs a Key, so, add an id, i think your table on data base have morecolumns, try the project on link please.

Comment: This seems to be working. But when I press the button to load the data, I get an unhandled exception, saying: "The entity type Entries is not part of the model for the current context."

Comment: how the link cannot work ? I updated the question now

Comment: i cant open pastebin.com, this link showme dont resolve dns or ip

Comment: @DanielCîrstea please see, the answare updated, i add a link to github

Comment: read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx